# Taking two values from two list of tuples and multiplying

Tags: python, tuples, tf-idf

I am calculating the TD IDF of a list of tuples. I have calculated the TF value and it is stored in a list of tuples and I have calcualted the IDF value which is also stored in a list of tuples. For example:

`>>print(tf)`

`[(('0', 'CD'), 0.0036429872495446266), (('09:00', 'CD'), 0.0018214936247723133)`

Then

`>>print(idf`

`[(('0', 'CD'), 2.4385423487861106), (('09:00', 'CD'), 2.739572344450092)`

Now i want to multiple the value of `0.00364` by `2.43854` and then `0.001821` by `2.739` so that the output is in any format in a way that it goes:
`word, td*idf`

Ofc these are just 2 values of many but I'm not sure how do i iterate through both lists whilst keeping the "calculated value" to the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension in order to multiply the second terms in the tuples from both lists and build a new list with the specified structure:

```
tf = [(('0', 'CD'), 0.0036429872495446266), (('09:00', 'CD'), 0.0018214936247723133)]
idf = [(('0', 'CD'), 2.4385423487861106), (('09:00', 'CD'), 2.739572344450092)]

[(t1, v1*v2) for (t1, v1), (t2, v2) in zip(tf,idf)]
```

**Output**

```
[(('0', 'CD'), 0.008883578684102406), (('09:00', 'CD'), 0.004990113560018382)]
```

**Update**

If items within the tuples are not always in the same order, for example:

```
tf = [(('0', 'CD'), 0.0036429872495446266), (0.0018214936247723133, ('09:00', 'CD'))]
```

you can order them using:

```
[(t,f) if isinstance(t, tuple) else (f,t) for t, f in tf]
# [(('0', 'CD'), 0.0036429872495446266), (('09:00', 'CD'), 0.0018214936247723133)]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Can accept the answer in 9minutes

Comment: If the order of my list varies after each run, and I still want to do the calculation, what would be my approach to this? As your code assumes the words are in the same order?

Comment: Thanks but I think you misunderstood. I mean for example if the order of the tuples were different i.e. `[(('09:00', 'CD'), 0.0018214936247723133),(('0', 'CD'), 0.0036429872495446266))]`

Comment: I see. well the thing is that it is a different question that will lead to a completely different answer. I'd suggest you ask again and I'm sure you'll get a solution pretty soon :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just use list comprehension. Be warned, if the order of words is off, you will end of attaching the wrong td*idf to the wrong word. To avoid mismatched values to words, perhaps you want to `sort` the list of tuples first. However, if the lengths of `tf` and `idf` are different, then it will truncate the longer list to match the shorter one. This will also be problematic in that words may not match if there is an extra tuple shifting every tuple down one index.

```
result = [(tup1[0], tup1[1]*tup2[1]) for tup1, tup2 in zip(tf,idf)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can transform them both to dicts:

```
tf = [(('0', 'CD'), 0.0036429872495446266), (('09:00', 'CD'), 0.0018214936247723133)]

tf_dict = dict(tf)
print(tf_dict) 
>> {('0', 'CD'): 0.0036429872495446266, ('09:00', 'CD'): 0.0018214936247723133}

idf = [(('0', 'CD'), 2.4385423487861106), (('09:00', 'CD'), 2.739572344450092)]
idf_dict = dict(idf)


# now you have same keys in both dicts
res = {k: v*idf_dict[v] for k,v in tf_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tf =[(('0', 'CD'), 0.0036429872495446266), (('09:00', 'CD'), 0.0018214936247723133)]
idf= [(('0', 'CD'), 2.4385423487861106), (('09:00', 'CD'), 2.739572344450092)]
output = [(i[0],i[1]*j[1]) for i,j in zip(tf,idf)]
```

the output will be:

```
 [(('0', 'CD'), 0.008883578684102406), (('09:00', 'CD'), 0.004990113560018382)]
```